# How to do Chain manipulation in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

How can I add another `select` based on the value of the first `select`?

When the first `select` box changes, I want to make an AJAX request to fetch values for another `select`, based on the values of the first `select`, and insert them as options in a new `select` in the DOM.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Populate City Dropdown Using jQuery Ajax</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.country").change(function(){
        var selectedCountry = $(".country option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process-request.php",
            data: { country : selectedCountry } 
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#response").html(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Country:</label>
                <select class="country">
                    <option>Select</option>
                    <option value="usa">United States</option>
                    <option value="india">India</option>
                    <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
                </select> 
            </td>
            <td id="response">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I can only see 1 select in your HTML, but with jQuery you can simply use `$("#select2").val($("#select1").val());` if you want to set the second select to the value of the first.

Comment: What does `process-request.php` return? 
If you run this code, what is the content of `<td id="response"></td>` after selecting a country?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.country").change(function(){
        var selectedCountry = $(".country option:selected").val();
        
//sample data - code starts here
        var data  = '[{"id":1,"name":"Karnataka"},{"id":2,"name":"Karnataka2"}, {"id":3,"name":"Karnataka3"}]';
        data = jQuery.parseJSON( data ); 
//sample data ends here

       $('#response').append(' <label>State:</label><select class="state" id="state"> </select> ');

       $('#response select').append($("<option />").val('').text('Select'));

       $.each(data,function(index, value){

             $('#response select').append($("<option  />").val(value.id).text(value.name));
       });
//add above code to your ajax success - code ends here.. 

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "process-request.php",
            data: { country : selectedCountry } 
        }).done(function(data) {
            
                                                    

        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Country:</label>
                <select class="country">
                    <option>Select</option>
                    <option value="usa">United States</option>
                    <option value="india">India</option>
                    <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
                </select> 
            </td>
            <td id="response">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try this syntax of AJAX.

```
$("select.country").change(function(){
var selectedCountry = $(".country option:selected").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process-request.php",
    data: { country : selectedCountry } 
    success: function(data){$("#response").html(data);},
    error: function(err){}
})
```

});

Comment: Why? What you suggested is the old style of jQuery, the code in the question is actually better!?